# Regarding some elementary transformations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was trying to follow a math forum thread when suddenly I stumbled upon a transformation that I just couldn't understand. It goes as follows:

$$v = \sqrt{ \frac{2 U}{r} - \frac{2 U}{r_0}}
\implies v = \frac{dr}{dt} =  \sqrt{ \frac{2 U r_0  - 2 U r } {rr_0}}$$

Can anyone please explain me how we got from the fist statement to the second? What sort of rules are employed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Forget about the square root.
Do you know how to calculate $\frac12+\frac13$?